How to add a new diagram type to Camunda modeler?
I am working on Camunda modeler to add a diagram type based on the open source project. I would like to add a brand-new diagram type beyond the default diagrams like BPMN DMN and CMMN. I can call it Activity Diagram. Adding a new diagram means Camunda engine should be able to recognize and show it on the UI. For example, I should be able to run the following code without any issue in the base project.
const element = event.element;
  if (is(element, 'bpmn:ManualTask')) {
    // Code to open and render the new Activity Diagram
    const activityDiagramXML = `<activityDiagram xmlns="http://example.com/schema/activityDiagram">
      <metrics id="metrics1"/>
      <operation id="operation1"/>
    </activityDiagram>`;
    
    BPMNJS.importXML(activityDiagramXML, (err) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Activity Diagram rendered');
      } else {
        console.error('Failed to render Activity Diagram', err);
      }
    });
  }

Unfortunately, the default importXML function only support default xml tags like bpmn:Definitions.
Here is the piece of code of the function.
BaseViewer.prototype.importXML = async function importXML(xml, bpmnDiagram) {

    const self = this;
  
    function ParseCompleteEvent(data) {
      return self.get('eventBus').createEvent(data);
    }
  
    let aggregatedWarnings = [];
    try {
  
      // hook in pre-parse listeners +
      // allow xml manipulation
  
      /**
       * A `import.parse.start` event.
       *
       * @event BaseViewer#ImportParseStartEvent
       * @type {ImportParseStartEvent}
       */
      xml = this._emit('import.parse.start', { xml: xml }) || xml;
  
      let parseResult;
      try {
        parseResult = await this._moddle.fromXML(xml, 'bpmn:Definitions');
      } catch (error) {
        this._emit('import.parse.complete', {
          error
        });
  
        throw error;
      }
  
      let definitions = parseResult.rootElement;
      const references = parseResult.references;
      const parseWarnings = parseResult.warnings;
      const elementsById = parseResult.elementsById;
  
      aggregatedWarnings = aggregatedWarnings.concat(parseWarnings);
  
      // hook in post parse listeners +
      // allow definitions manipulation
  
      /**
       * A `import.parse.complete` event.
       *
       * @event BaseViewer#ImportParseCompleteEvent
       * @type {ImportParseCompleteEvent}
       */
      definitions = this._emit('import.parse.complete', ParseCompleteEvent({
        error: null,
        definitions: definitions,
        elementsById: elementsById,
        references: references,
        warnings: aggregatedWarnings
      })) || definitions;
  
      const importResult = await this.importDefinitions(definitions, bpmnDiagram);
  
      aggregatedWarnings = aggregatedWarnings.concat(importResult.warnings);
  
      /**
       * A `import.parse.complete` event.
       *
       * @event BaseViewer#ImportDoneEvent
       * @type {ImportDoneEvent}
       */
      this._emit('import.done', { error: null, warnings: aggregatedWarnings });
  
      return { warnings: aggregatedWarnings };
    } catch (err) {
      let error = err;
      aggregatedWarnings = aggregatedWarnings.concat(error.warnings || []);
      addWarningsToError(error, aggregatedWarnings);
  
      error = checkValidationError(error);
  
      this._emit('import.done', { error, warnings: error.warnings });
  
      throw error;
    }
};

How can I add a new diagram type to Camunda modeler and make the use of xml tags like <activityDiagram> and <operation> possible?
I wrote 2 files, namely, activityDiagramModdle.js and ActivityDiagramRendered.js to support the new diagram type and registered them properly to make Camunda model recognize them. But when I try to render the new diagram type, it causes the following error: failed to parse document as <bpmn:Definitions>. Any help or suggestion would be welcome.
Here are my files.
activityDiagramModdle.js
export default {
  name: 'ActivityDiagram',
  prefix: 'ad',
  uri: 'http://example.com/schema/activityDiagram',
  xml: {
    tagAlias: 'lowerCase'
  },
  types: [
    {
      name: 'ActivityDiagram',
      superClass: ['Element'],
      properties: [
        {
          name: 'metrics',
          isMany: true,
          type: 'ad:Metrics'
        },
        {
          name: 'operation',
          isMany: true,
          type: 'ad:Operation'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Metrics',
      superClass: ['Element'],
      properties: [
        {
          name: 'id',
          isAttr: true,
          type: 'String'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Operation',
      superClass: ['Element'],
      properties: [
        {
          name: 'id',
          isAttr: true,
          type: 'String'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

ActivityDiagramRendered.js
import BaseRenderer from 'diagram-js/lib/draw/BaseRenderer';

export default class ActivityDiagramRenderer extends BaseRenderer {
  constructor(eventBus, bpmnRenderer) {
    super(eventBus, 2000);

    this.bpmnRenderer = bpmnRenderer;
  }

  canRender(element) {
    return /^ad:/.test(element.type);
  }

  drawShape(parentNode, element) {
    const shape = this.bpmnRenderer.drawShape(parentNode, element);

    if (element.type === 'ad:Metrics') {
      shape.attr({
        fill: 'green'
      });
    } else if (element.type === 'ad:Operation') {
      shape.attr({
        fill: 'blue'
      });
    }

    return shape;
  }
}

ActivityDiagramRenderer.$inject = ['eventBus', 'bpmnRenderer'];


